# How to disable the selection of individual cells of the UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Once the user taps a cell triggering an action, I want to disable the user interaction and then reenable user interaction when the action has finished. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just check  for the condition in TableView delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *categoryIdentifier = @"Category";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //Way to stop to choose the cell selection
     if(indexpath.row == 0){
         cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
         // OR 
         cell.userInteractionEnabled=False;
     }
     //while rest of the cells will remain active, i.e Touchable

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: this is just for specific cell in which you don't the cell selection. Otherwise there is no need to have this ;)

Comment: I agree with "cell.userIneractionEnabled=False;" but changing the selection style does *NOT* disable user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `BOOL` variable that you set to true when the action has started. Then implement the `-[tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` method of the tableview's delegate so that it returns `nil` when the variable is currently true for that index path.

Answer (score 1):

or you can make the selectionStyle when action is running

```
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```